# SQL Query progress using PostgreSQL or My SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, postgresql

**Introduction**

Hello everyone.
Working on web application management I often find myself having a problem that I have never solved with my current knowledge.
In my applications, most data extraction processes are long-lasting due to complex queries and large amounts of data.
In fact, the waiting time of a data extraction through PHP is largely spent by the *QUERY EXECUTION* (in most cases).
Suppose we have this common situation

[image]

**Question**

At this point my question is: Is there a solution for know at what point of query execution process has arrived and then do a query trace for have my [PROGRESS QUERY %]?

**My solution**

So far the solution I have used are this: "Query time history"

When I run a data extraction query with specific parameters i save in the table the duration of the query and every time that query is executed with those parameters i overwrite the rescheduled duration with the average of all durations.
So I can have an estimate based on an average, obviously ignoring other parameters that can affect the duration of a query and i can call a client side function based on seconds estimated and populate the [PROGRESS QUERY %].

Example: (i use boostrap progress bar for view)

*HTML*

```
<!-- where "data-seconds" are the average seconds of the execution saved in my query time history table -->
<button type="button" id="runQuery" data-seconds="500">Get Data</button>    
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">
  </div>
</div>
```

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
$("#runQuery").on("click", function() {
    var currentSeconds = 0;
    var totalSeconds = parseFloat($(this).data("seconds"));
    var $progressBar = $(".progress-bar");
    var progressPercentage = 0;
    var execution;

    $.ajax({
        url: "scriptForQueryExecution.php", type: "POST", beforeSend: function() {
            execution = setInterval(function() {
                progressPercentage = currentSeconds / totalSeconds * 100;
                $progressBar.css("width", progressPercentage + '%').attr("aria-valuenow", progressPercentage);

                currentSeconds++;
            }, 1000);
        }, success: function() {
            $progressBar.css("width", '100%').attr("aria-valuenow", 100);
            clearInterval(execution);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You want a progress meter to inform the user when to expect a query to complete? You need a separate database connection with privileges to query the execution plans for other users' queries and other database system information. Effectively a debugger or profiler. Which RDBMS are you using? MY SQL, SQL SERVER, etc? The answer will change wildly for each RDBMS, and some won't give you what you want.

Comment: I use PostgresSQL, My SQL, MariaDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB supports *"progress reporting"* within their process lists, through `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST` which update progress information with an 5-second interval (default). Details can be found here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/progress-reporting/.

PostgreSQL supports progress reporting too, albeit only for the `VACUUM` command: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/progress-reporting.html

All you need to do is query this info with separate XHR requests, and animate your progress indicator with CSS animations.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you've probably thought of this, but you could write a query that determines the number of rows in the table using `select count([ID]) from dbo.MyTable` which should take less that 1 second and then build in some calculation on the client side that calculates the current number of rows divided by the total number of rows in the table...

Comment: I search for a "Query-Trace" if exist.